# Get parent Control of the given id of SAP UI5 Elements

Tags: sapui5

I have a MultiComboBox(id = *__xmlview1--cdsRepairErrorCatMultiCombo*) UI5 element which has a input field (id is *__xmlview1--cdsRepairErrorCatMultiCombo-inner*) as shown in the picture.

If I try to get Control of the input element by *sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview1--cdsRepairErrorCatMultiCombo-inner")*, it returns undefined as the main Control is '**MultiComboBox**' which you will get by *sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview1--cdsRepairErrorCatMultiCombo")*.

So my question to get a parent Control by only knowing the id of the child element.
ex: I have the id of the input field and I would like to get access to parent MultiComboBox.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

PS: **I am trying to get the Control from outside system**. That's why I have used the approach to get the Control using the method 'sap.ui.getCore().byId'

[image]

Comment: I believe you are trying to fix the wrong problem. It is not a common thing to get the SAPUI5 control for a global element ID. You rather use the local this.getView().byId() function. Try to structure your app in a way that you can use local IDs.

Answer (score 1):

UI5 has a very well defined input lifecycle - validator, datatypes etc. You want to create a JSON model. Bind the JSON model to your input and take any data out of this model.

Never, ever use composed ID's.

I don't understand your example(why is there and input in a multicombobox?, sound like you want a sap.m.MultiInput), but f you really want to walk over parent/child path use the framework methods:

```js
 this.getView().byId("myMultiComboBoxChild").getParent()
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject%23methods/getParent